# What is the word for a sentence that initially sounds profound or deep, that is, in fact, meaningless or empty?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm sure I saw, recently, a word for this, but I can no longer remember, or find, it.

Comment: Philosopher Stephen Law has written about 'pseudo-profundity', 'deepity' and 'trite-nalogy': http://stephenlaw.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/pseudo-profundity-from-believing.html 
The term 'false profundity' is also an option.

Comment: Great article, thanks, exactly the concept I'm searching for a word for

Comment: [Shakespeare](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/macbeth.5.5.html) (and Faulkner) had a phrase for it - *a tale told by an idiot, full of sound and fury, signifying nothing.*

Comment: "profound and deep"?

Comment: I like this one: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IceCreamKoan

Comment: How about "torrid zephyr"?

Comment: Or "superheated plasma"?

Comment: '[Fauxlosophy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fauxlosophy)' also a possibility.

Comment: Related (but arguably not duplicate) question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158600/what-is-a-word-to-describe-a-statement-that-seems-meaningless

Comment: Sounds like B.S. to me.

Comment: @AE  I was just going to say "philosophy" :-) .   Or maybe,  "spaaaaace!"

Comment: how about "a tweet"

Comment: A Donnie Darko.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Possibly [*platitude*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/platitude):

> A trite or banal remark or statement, especially one expressed as if it were original or significant.

Comment: I think this is the perfect word for what you're looking for. A couple of other answers fit decently, but I think this one fits best by far. Upvoted appropriately. For examples, consider "Hard work always pays off", "Everything happens for a reason", "What doesn't kill you makes you stronger", etc.

Comment: @DoktorJ: see also http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/149/was-nietzsche-making-fun-of-the-military-mindset-when-he-said-that-which-does-n :)

Comment: I don't think this fits because a platitude is not meant to impress; it is merely meant to persuade.  And triteness is in stark contrast to the profundity the sentence is intended to convey.

Comment: A platitude never "sounds profound or deep" - it literally means *flatness*.

Comment: @MatthewHannigan and ekhumoro: there are two aspects to a platitude: the intended force and the actual content. the triteness and flatness applies to the *actual* content of the statement, which *is* in stark contrast to the profundity of its intended force.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps *[grandiloquence](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/grandiloquent#grandiloquent)*

> Pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner, especially in a way that is intended to impress:
>   *a grandiloquent celebration of Spanish glory*

Similarly, *[bombast](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bombast)*

> High-sounding language with little meaning, used to impress people.

[both *Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Comment: Naturally, *pompous bombast* is more grandiloquent than *bombast* alone.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger How about *pompous bombastic grandiloquent platitudes!*

Comment: Funny how words often have the qualities of their definition.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Best be curt!

Answer (score 17):

I good word for this might be meretricious, which means, courtesy of [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/meretricious):

> Apparently attractive but having in reality no value or integrity.

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it describes pretty accurately.

Answer (score 11):

If done intentionally then I might say *sophistry*, which the OED defines as:

> a. Specious but fallacious reasoning; employment of arguments which are intentionally deceptive.

In offices it's also quite common to refer to what you describe using an impolite term for bull excrement.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, I think "specious" is actually more apt in this context than "sophistry".

Answer (score 10):

Were you perhaps thinking of *[deepity](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Deepity)*?

> The term refers to a statement that is apparently profound but actually asserts a triviality on one level and something meaningless on another.

E.g.: "love is just a word"

> On one level the statement is perfectly true (i.e., love is a word) but the deeper meaning of the phrase is false; love is many things — a feeling, an emotion, a condition — and not simply a word.

Comment: I think Daniel Dennett defined it as a statement made ambiguous by the inclusion or omission of quotation marks, such that one meaning is true but trivial, and the other is false but would be profound if it were true.

Answer (score 10):

"BS," is the most popularly used term, and has attained some formal credentials (see Harry G. Frankfurt "On Bullshit," Princeton University Press).

Answer (score 5):

It can be called a ***wind*** and you can use ***windy*** as an adjective.

> *wind* - Empty, pompous, or boastful talk; meaningless rhetoric.
>
> *windy* - Using or expressed in many words that sound impressive but mean little
>
> <sup>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The first word that came to my mind was "pretentious."

> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is
>   actually possessed.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody has yet suggested (or even mentioned) [truism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/truism).

Comment: I decided not to mention it because a truism isn't "in fact, meaningless or empty": a truism is just true.

Comment: A Truism is a Platitude and most Platitudes fall into the category of Truisms. Ex: If you are good you will do good. Thank you Tim this is a perfectly valid answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

A good adjective is

> pompous

Something pompous is always very showy, but it is implied that its real value is less than at first glance. It can be used for a person's mannerisms, but also for sentences/phrasing and in many other cases.

Comment: And *pomposity* would be the noun (which is what OP asks for).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the word **rhetoric**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: [Hollow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hollow)

> Without real significance or value:

Easier to use in a conversation then some of the more formal suggestions