# Someone who uses too many descriptive words to deceptively seem intelligent

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

What is a word in the English language to describe someone who purposely and excessively uses too many complex words, usually looking them up in a thesaurus, to seem more intelligent in their writings?

I found the term "waxing prolix". But, this doesn't seem to cover the fact that the person is doing this purposely to seem more intelligent than they actually are.

An example. "The feature is a pastiche of mediocrity and boorish cynicism. They are a political and artistic hack pandering to an assemblage of bitter philistines." The person could have just as easily said, "I'm not a fan of this movie or it's actors".

They simply sound like they are trying to sound more intelligent by using an arsenal of words that are not often used in the common tongue. Perhaps elevating themselves above their own audience?

Not a duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204241/what-is-the-word-for-a-sentence-that-initially-sounds-profound-or-deep-that-is) because the accepted answer to that question does not describe the word I am looking for.

Comment: bib gives "**grandiloquence** [/ grandiloquent]:

Pompous or extravagant in language, style, or manner, especially in a way that is intended to impress: a grandiloquent celebration of Spanish glory" and 'bombast[ic] there.

Comment: You can now look up synonyms for 'grandiloquence / grandiloquent' if you are convinced that there is a better word. Or if you just hope there is. But the question is certainly a duplicate; the fact that you're not totally happy with answers given there makes no difference. You could offer a bonus there when you have enough rep points.

Comment: I can't answer the question so I will post a comment instead..., but how about "sesquipedalian" which can mean the overuse of long words?